# Windows program claims no disk free space under Wine

Tags: wine

A Windows game refuses to save any games because it claims there's no disk space free. I've used XP and 98 modes in winecfg, and this is a 32-bit wineprefix (at least, I'm pretty sure it is; not sure how to confirm). My suspicion is that it's the old favourite problem of having more than 2GB free space, for which we used to have a little fix script back when we used OS/2 and there were DOS programs that had trouble. Is there a way to get Wine to announce less disk space than there actually is?

edit for version numbers: Debian Testing (Stretch), Wine 1.8.5 as distributed by Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much knowledge of Wine, I'd work around that problem making the program happy and giving it a disk that is smaller than 2 GB.

It's very simple. First, create a file filled with 0s that is 512 MB (or more, but less than 2048):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=smalldisk.img bs=1M count=512
```

Next, format it using the default file system:

```
mkfs smalldisk.img
```

Move the existing directory to a temporary name:

```
mv .wine-demo .wine-demo-orig
```

Mount the new disk as a loop device at the original location:

```
sudo mount smalldisk.img .wine-demo
sudo chown your-user-name: .wine-demo
```

Copy the entire tree in:

```
cp -r .wine-demo-orig/* .wine-demo
```

And run the program from there. If it still doesn't work, then you'll need a different solution.

(There is, unfortunately, a chance that it won't work. If it can't handle 2 GB of disk space, it will probably not handle 2 GB of RAM...)

Provided it works, I suggest your unmount it and put it in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/path/to/smalldisk.img /path/to/mount ext4 auto,noexec,rw,loop,fmask=0177,dmask=0077,user 0 0
```

In this line `fmask` and `dmask` are mask permissions for files and directories. Notice that they are the opposite of what you would use with `chmod`. That is, `7` stands for *no permissions* (`---`) and `0` stands for *full permissions* (`wrx`). Read more here: [fstab Permission Masks Explained](http://www.omaroid.com/fstab-permission-masks-explained/).

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Any particular reason for using vfat here?

Comment: In fact, I can't put a wineprefix on a vfat volume, as it uses symlinks. So I'm trying this with ext4.

Comment: No specific reason, just thought it was playing safe, since I'm not versed in Wine.

Comment: Yay! It's working. I'll suggest edits that will make your answer ready to accept!

Comment: I suspect the cause of the problem could be a 64 to 32 bug in the wine, or a limitation of the win98/winxp api. Also I faced this problem, but unfortunately this workaround did't come in my mind. Wonderful solution!